Node.js application on SAP BTP continuously increasing memory usage even after query execution stops
We have deployed a Node.js application on SAP Business Technology Platform (BTP) to handle database queries. We've noticed that the application's memory usage starts increasing by 5-10 MB after every few seconds, even when there are no active queries being executed.
We have tried setting optimize_memory to true as recommended in the documentation, but it doesn't seem to resolve the issue. Additionally, when the memory reaches around 400 MB out of the allocated 500 MB, the application crashes while using optimize_memory to true.
Here's a summary of the key points:

Node.js application deployed on SAP BTP.
Memory usage increases gradually, even when no queries are being executed.
Tried setting optimize_memory to true without success.
Application crashes when memory usage reaches around 400 MB out of the allocated 500 MB.
*** also when suddenly memory starts incresing CPU utilization also shows 100+% on sap BTP.

We are seeking advice or suggestions on how to troubleshoot and resolve this memory usage issue effectively on SAP BTP. Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!
In response to the memory usage issue on our Node.js application deployed on SAP BTP, we tried setting the optimize_memory parameter to true, as recommended in the documentation. Our expectation was that enabling this option would help optimize memory usage and prevent memory leaks, ultimately resolving the issue of memory consumption gradually increasing over time, even when no queries are actively running. However, despite implementing this configuration change, the problem persisted, and the application continued to experience memory growth until it eventually crashed.
also checked Heap Profile to find memory leak, also checked memoryUsage using node:process, Optimized code.
but no luck.
